# Data frame mode function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

HI I want to ask I am using df.mode() function to find the most common in one row. This will give me an extra column how could I have only one column? I am using df.mode(axis=1)
for example I have a data frame

```
   0 1 2 3 4
1  1 0 1 1 1
2  0 1 0 0 1 
3  0 0 1 1 0
```

so I want the output

```
1  1
2  0
3  0
```

but I am getting

```
1  1 NaN
2  0 NaN
3  0 NaN
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: `df.mode(1)` ?  .

Answer (score 0):

The code you tried gives the expected output in Python 3.7.6 with Pandas 1.0.3.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[[1, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0]], 
    index=[1, 2, 3])
df
```

```
    0   1   2   3   4
1   1   0   1   1   1
2   0   1   0   0   1
3   0   0   1   1   0
```

```
df.mode(axis=1)
```

```
    0
1   1
2   0
3   0
```

Comment: I use exactly the same but if I use it on my big data set it won't be like this then have two columns as I illustrated. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

There could be different data types in your columns and mode cannot be used to compare column of different data type.

Use str() or int() to convert your df.series to a suitable data type. Make sure that the data type is consistent in the df before employing mode(axis=1)